# How do I connect to a RabbitMQ instance running in a local Docker container on Windows?

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq, queue, port

I've installed Docker Desktop and have the latest RabbitMQ image running there. I also have a java application running locally in Intellij that is trying to connect to RabbitMQ on port 5672 but it cannot connect. How can I expose the RabbitMQ running in Docker on port 5672? I do not see any such configuration options and can't seem to get any commands to run via the provided cli.

This is what the "Ports" section looks like in the Inspect tab within Docker:
[image]

Comment: How did you start RabbitMQ originally; what `docker run -p` or Docker Compose `ports:` options did you use?  You will need to delete and recreate the container with the right options.

Answer (score 0):

You probably started a docker run command with incorrect parameters, and your docker rabbitmq container failed to bind. To be sure that everything is correct try the following

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.9.5-management
    hostname: rabbit
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
```

After `docker-compose up -d` , this will be the result:

[image]

Once you hit localhost:15672, using guest;guest you should be able to also see your connections, queues and so on.

Comment: Do you know how I can edit this yml file? I don't see an option for it within the docker desktop app and I'm not sure where it lives on my harddrive. I was wondering about this too, I'm not sure how to access the .sh file where all the commands live and stuff. Maybe I should just be doing through a CLI on windows instead of using the docker app

Comment: you dont need docker desktop for this.

simply make a new folder "rabbitmq" folder on your disk. It can be anywhere you want, after that create a new empty file called **docker-compose.yml** and paste the contents inside from above. After that simply run docker-compose up -d from your preffered CLI.

Answer (score -1):

In docker Desktop you should be able to see in which port Docker is running. And you can access the console through the browser. If that is the case, the problem is in your app, probably your properties or something like that